# Variable values based on class

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

Why can't I change a scss variable based on a class? I want the variable to be green when in class dark-mode.

Css:

```
$test: red;

@mixin darkTheme {
  $test: green;
}

.theme-dark {
  @include darkTheme();

  .test {
    background-color: $test;
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<body class="dark-mode">
  <div class="test">test</div>
</body>
```

How do I accomplish this? What I don't want is 2 variables.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of **Variable Scoping**.

> In Sass, all variables declared *outside of a mixin or function* will have a global scope and can be referenced in any Sass selector that uses the variable. ([source](https://anotheruiguy.gitbooks.io/sassintherealworld_book-i/handy-tools/variable-scoping.html))

This means that any variable value set *inside* of a mixin or function is only available within that mixin or function, even if the variable was previously set globally.

---

### Switching between different sets of Sass variables

#### Partials

You could have a partial file for each theme, and import those under each theme's parent class.

_theme-dark.scss

```
$background-color: #000;
$text-color: #fff;
```

_theme-light.scss

```
$background-color: #fff;
$text-color: #000;
```

_themed-page.scss

```
body {
    background: $background-color;
    color: $text-color;
}
```

theme-styles.scss

```
.theme-dark {
    @import "theme-dark";
    @import "themed-page";
}

.theme-light {
    @import "theme-light";
    @import "themed-page";
}
```

---

#### Maps

Another option is to store the theme values in a map and have a utility function to retrieve the desired value. ([source](https://codeburst.io/a-successful-sass-theme-structure-ca9d1c477dc7))

_theme-variables.scss

```
$theme: 'default';

$theme-values: ( 
    'background-color': ( 
        'default': #eee,
        'light': #fff,
        'dark': #000
    ),
    'text-color': ( 
        'default': #333,
        'light': #000,
        'dark': #fff
    )
);

@function theme-value($key) {
    $map: map-get($theme-values, $key);
    @return map-get($map, $theme);
}
```

_themed-page.scss

```
body {
    background: theme-value('background-color');
    color: theme-value('text-color');
}
```

theme-styles.scss

```
.theme-dark {
    $theme: 'dark';
    @import "themed-page";
}

.theme-light {
    $theme: 'light';
    @import "themed-page";
}
```